# Zend Checkbox issue

Tags: zend-framework, checkbox

I am writing a code in zend and I want to create muliple checkbox code to select data and after clicking the submit button to view the Information in the database, the code works fine but when it gets to the database the field does not display the choosen box instead it writes "array" in that field. here is my form code below..any suggestions higly appreciated

```
$Organisation_type = new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox('Organisation_type', array(
    'multiOptions' => array(
                        '1' =>' Start-up',
                        '2' =>' Sole Proprietor',
                        '3' =>' Partnership',
                        '4' =>' Close Corporation',
                        '5' =>' Company Trust',
                        '6' =>' Compny Propriety Limited',
                        '7' =>' Co-operative',
                        '8' =>' Non Profit Organization',
    )
));
$Organisation_type->setLabel('Organisation type'); 
$Organisation_type->setValue(array('Start-up', 'Sole Proprietor', 'Partnership', 'Close Corporation', 'Company Trust', 'Compny Propriety Limited', 'Co-operative', 'Non Profit Organization'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take care about what is in your variable you r saving in DB. For it you should try a var_dump($var);

Answer (score 0):

A checkbox group will always return an array... it is an array of checkboxes.

If you want to store this data in a single column then it will need converting to another format.

The easiest way to do this is to convert the array or object to a JSON string

To encode an array to JSON:

```
    $json = json_encode($array);
```

To decode JSON back to an array:

```
    $array = json_decode($json);
```

You can also do this using the zend wrapper Zend_Json: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.json.html.